# How to correctly get mouse coordinates with JavaScript without JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am aware of the fact that variations of that question were asked many times before. Looking through Google output I found pages with examples like that:

```
function point_it(event) {
pos_x = event.offsetX ? (event.offsetX) : event.pageX - document.getElementById("pointer_div").offsetLeft;
pos_y = event.offsetY ? (event.offsetY) : event.pageY - document.getElementById("pointer_div").offsetTop;
document.pointform.form_x.value = pos_x;
document.pointform.form_y.value = pos_y;
}
```

The code works, but when I look at 
 [MouseEvent.offsetX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/offsetX) it says "This is an experimental technology...".

So my question is, is it save to use the above construction or not? Is it better to learn how to use JQuery?

Comment: jQuery IS javascript - therefore if you want to do this in plain vanilla JS, it CAN be done

Comment: It is better to learn javascript. Once you understand javascript you will know if you should use jquery or not.

Comment: If IE 6 supports this, the other browsers must support it.

Comment: @Darren Sweeney what do you mean by "plain vanilla" JS? Isn't my example written in JS?

Comment: Yes, but your question asked whether you could do it in Javascript or better to learn jQuery - a common term for JS without jQuery is vanilla JS

Comment: @DarrenSweeney Thanks, I didn't know that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Please try this**

```
function getClickPosition(e) {
    var xPosition = e.clientX;
    var yPosition = e.clientY;
}
```

Call this function on "onClick" event. [You can get the coordinates](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_clientx.asp).
Output the coordinates of the mouse pointer when the mouse button is clicked on an element.

Comment: That function is pretty simple and works fine. Thank you.